Some images get corrupted when uploaded to firebase bucket
I am using the below code to upload images to firebase bucket, it works correctly most of the time but the images get corrupt sometimes randomly.
I have also noticed that size of all corrupt images are in multiples of 256 KB (i.e. 512 KB, 1536 KB etc.)
Attaching code for reference:
import android.net.Uri
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageMetadata
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference

class ImageUploader {

    private var storage: FirebaseStorage? = null
    private var storageReference: StorageReference? = null

    fun uploadImage(uri: Uri) {
        // Initialize Firebase Storage
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        storageReference = storage!!.reference

        // File metadata
        val metadata = StorageMetadata.Builder()
            .setContentType("image/jpeg")
            .build()

        // File reference
        val fileUri: Uri = Uri.parse("file://$uri")
        val fileName = "example.jpg"
        val fileReference = storageReference?.child(fileName)

        // Upload task
        val uploadTask = fileReference?.putFile(fileUri, metadata)

        // Add success listener
        uploadTask?.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
            // Handle successful upload
            
            // Delete the image from local storage upon successful upload
            deleteImageFromLocalStorage(uri)
        }?.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            // Handle failed upload
        }
    }
    
    private fun deleteImageFromLocalStorage(uri: Uri) {
        // Add code to delete the image from local storage
    }
}

I also added checks to see if image was corrupt before uploading but that was not the case.
